# Create the YAML file for a ConfigMap without creating the corresponding Kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

## Question

Is there a way to get the YAML manifest file of a configmap, without creating the corresponding Kubernetes resource?

At the moment I'm doing this:

```bash
kubectl create configmap <name> --from-file="<name>"
kubectl get configmap <name> -o yaml > <name>.yaml
kubectl delete configmap <name>
```

Is there some simple way to achieve this without having to create a temporary resource in the Kubernetes cluster?

### Example

Directory structure:

```
myheader/
  +- handler.lua
  +- schema.lua
```

File `handler.lua`:

```lua
local MyHeader = {}

MyHeader.PRIORITY = 1000
MyHeader.VERSION = "1.0.0"

function MyHeader:header_filter(conf)
  -- do custom logic here
  kong.response.set_header("myheader", conf.header_value)
end

return MyHeader
```

File `schema.lua`:

```lua
return {
  name = "myheader",
  fields = {
    {
      config = {
        type = "record",
        fields = {
          {
            header_value = {
              type = "string",
              default = "roar",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

I can obtain the manifest file `myheader-configmap.yaml` like this:

```bash
kubectl create configmap myheader --from-file "myheader/"
kubectl get configmap myheader -o yaml > myheader-configmap.yaml
kubectl delete configmap myheader
```

Is there some command or anything else to obtain the same manifest file, without having to preemptively create the corresponding Kubernetes resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :)

You can use the following command:

```bash
kubectl create configmap <name> --from-file=<file-name> --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

If you want to save it to a file, you can just use bash redirection, e.g:

```bash
kubectl create configmap <name> --from-file=<file-name> --dry-run=client -o yaml > filename.yaml
```

You can specify additional argument like `--namespace=default`